# Fade without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this function to open and close elements onclick.
How can I add some fade effect without using jQuery?

```
function toggle_visibility(){
  for(var i = 0,len = arguments.length;i < len;i++){
    var e = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style,d = e.display;
    e.display = (d == "block") ? "none" : "block";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css3 transition and opacity to do this

```
#block {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.out { opacity: 0; }
.in { opacity: 1; }
```

then use out or in class to hide or show the element

Comment: So I need to alter the function to add/remove a class?

Comment: Yes that would be the way to go

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I need help with that. In jQuery it's easy, but how do I do it with pure javaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function like this:

```
var toggleFade = function(element, time, callback) {
    var timeStep = 50;
    var step = timeStep / time;
    var toValue = 1;
    if (element.style.display != 'none') {
        step = -step;
        toValue = 0;
        element.style.opacity = element.style.opacity || 1;        
    } else {
        element.style.opacity = element.style.opacity || 0;  
        element.style.display = 'block';        
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var newVal = +element.style.opacity + step;

        if (newVal < 0 && step < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            element.style.opacity = 0;
            element.style.display = 'none'
            callback && callback();
        } else if (newVal > 1 && step > 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            element.style.opacity = 1;
            callback && callback();
        } else
            element.style.opacity = newVal;
    }, timeStep);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXcnc/1/)