# jQuery convert to Plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert this jQuery code to ES6 and am having trouble with transitioning opacity. Is there an equivalent for jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` in ES6?

Here's my failed attempt at transitioning the opacity on the .screen element from 0 to 1 over 300ms.

CSS

```
.screen {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
background: rgba(26, 31, 33, 0.96)
}
```

JS

```
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        headerMenu.init();
    });

headerMenu = {

    init: function() {
        let header = document.querySelector('.site-header'),
            w = window,
            lastScrollTop = 0;

        const headerSize = () => {
            const st = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
            if ( st >= 180 ){
                header.classList.add('is-scrolling-down');
            } else {
                header.classList.remove('is-scrolling-down');
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        }

        w.addEventListener('load', headerSize);
        w.addEventListener('resize', headerSize);
        w.addEventListener('scroll', headerSize);

        w.addEventListener('load', () => {
            let burger = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-trigger'),
                mask = document.querySelector('.screen');

            const clickHandler = () => {
                if (burger.classList.contains('is-active')) {
                    burger.classList.remove('is-active');
                    mask.style.display = 'none';
                    mask.style.opacity = 0;
                    mask.style.transition = 'opacity 0.3s';
                    document.body.classList.remove('menu-is-active');

                } else {
                    mask.style.display = 'inline';
                    mask.style.opacity = 1;
                    burger.classList.add('is-active');                 
                    document.body.classList.add('menu-is-active');

                }
            }
            burger.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
            mask.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        })
    }
};

})();
```

jQuery version of the bottom section (using fadeIn and fadeOut) that works

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var burger = $('.mobile-menu-trigger'),
            mask = $('.screen');

        $('.mobile-menu-trigger, .screen').click(function(){
            if(burger.hasClass('is-active')) {
                burger.removeClass('is-active');
                mask.fadeOut(300);
                $('body').removeClass('menu-is-active');
              } else {
                mask.fadeIn(300);
                burger.addClass('is-active');
                $('body').addClass('menu-is-active');
              }
        });
    });
```

Any assistance with the last piece of this (or a better way to do it) would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the jQuery way is to query the current opacity abd then use a setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame to gradually increment. In ES6, though, I'd recommend using CSS3 transitions/transforms. Add/remove a fadein/out class and let the CSS do the heavy lifting

Comment: @Doug That sounds like the beginning of a good Answer post.

Comment: Actually, I searched for "fade without jquery" and found that question already has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133253/fade-without-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133253/fade-without-jquery)

Comment: I found that too and tried it with CSS, but since the body class `menu-is-active` is also added, there is nothing to transition to. `is-active` is added to `mobile-menu-trigger` and not `screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic foundation/example of using JavaScript to fade an element in/out ...

It's generally recommended to use `.requestAnimationFrame()` because it triggers when the browser is ready, instead of trying to force animations to happen on your schedule (which can cause glitchy results).  But requestAnimationFrame may operate faster/slower than expected -- for precise results, it may be worth researching how to manage the speed(s).

If you can get the CSS3 to work, it will save a lot of headache and be super smooth :)  Otherwise, I hope this is a good starting point on how to use JS to fade an element in/out.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('fadeTrigger');
const target = document.getElementById('target');

function fadeOut( el, time ){
  // get the amount to change the opacity based on
  // the assumed time
  let step = Number( ( 1 / time ).toFixed( 5 ) );
  // set the element's opacity to 100% (in this case [1])
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  // internal function to call/loop/recurssive over
  function fade(){
    // get the current opacity with the incremental change
    // that we discovered earlier on -- make sure it's a 
    // Number, since if this comes back as a string, it gets messy
    let opacity = Number( el.style.opacity ) - step;
    // Update the element with the new opacity
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    // Check if the opacity has hit zero [0]
    if( el.style.opacity > 0 ){
      // if the element does not have a zero [0] opacity, then
      // loop back on this function to continue
      window.requestAnimationFrame( fade );
    }else{
      // just to clean things up, if the opacity is less than 0
      // set it to zero [0]
      el.style.opacity = '0';
    }
  }
  fade();
}

// fadeIn is just like fadeOut -- but reversed
function fadeIn( el, time ){
  let step = Number( ( 1 / time ).toFixed( 5 ) );
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  function fade(){
    let opacity = Number( el.style.opacity ) + step;
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    if( el.style.opacity < 1 ){
      window.requestAnimationFrame( fade );
    }else{
      el.style.opacity = '1';
    }
  }
  fade();
}

btn.addEventListener('click', fadeTrigger);
// Generic switch control to trigger the fadeOut 
// and fadeIn functions
function fadeTrigger(){
  let state = btn.getAttribute('data-state');
  if( state === 'fadein' ){
    fadeOut( target, 30 );
    btn.setAttribute('data-state', 'fadeout');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Fade In';
  }else{
    fadeIn( target, 30 );
    btn.setAttribute('data-state', 'fadein');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Fade Out';
  }
}
```

```css
#target{
  height : 200px;
  width  : 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button data-state="fadein" id="fadeTrigger">Fade Out</button>
<br />
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll definitely try this out. Thanks Doug!